# Git error no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa

Tags: git, ssh, rsa, ssh-keys

I get the following error when using `git`:

```
$ git pull
Unable to negotiate with 172.16.42.42 port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Also discussed in https://public-inbox.org/git/CAHo1AWxzPsnLuT8JRWovtaRrGvRS8+0NyucU5K8VEnaL1xxW3Q@mail.gmail.com/T/#u

Answer (score 403, accepted):

With SSH, there are several different types of keys and RSA keys (the `ssh-rsa`) kind can support multiple kinds of signatures.  The signature type `ssh-rsa` refers to RSA with SHA-1, whereas the signature type `rsa-sha2-256` is RSA with SHA-256 and `rsa-sha2-512` is RSA with SHA-512.

In the case of Azure DevOps, it only supports the kind of RSA with SHA-1, and SHA-1 is considered very weak.  This essentially means that there are no secure ways to connect to it over SSH, and until they fix that, you're better off using HTTPS or a different hosting service.  GitHub, GitLab, and Bitbucket all support secure methods of authentication.

If you really need to use SSH with Azure DevOps at the moment, you can add an entry to your `~/.ssh/config` file to work around this:

```
Host ssh.dev.azure.com
    User git
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

However, be aware that this is a workaround and it's known to be insecure, so you should contact Azure DevOps about this problem and switch to HTTPS until they do, or move elsewhere.

Comment: And it maybe worth checking every season or two and removing if the host is ever updated to support better cyphers.

Comment: I got this issue after Cygwin's git updated 2.32 => 2.34, this answer fixed it, thank you!

Comment: This helped a colleague with a very recent Git installation, connecting to Azure DevOps Server 2020u1. Others on the team do not need it yet, so this is likely something new in Git. DevOps docs already have [a FAQ about this issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops#q-what-do-i-do-if-im-still-prompted-for-my-password-and-git_ssh_commandssh--v-git-fetch-shows-no-mutual-signature-algorithm).

Comment: Unfortunately putting this option to `~/.ssh/config` might break other software relying on older OpenSSH. I ended up using a deprecated name `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` instead of `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms` (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3468#issuecomment-965152050)).

Comment: The value in "Host" must be compatible with the domain in use eg: "some-client@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:v3/some-client/some-path/some-repo" . In this example the value in "Host" ("~/.ssh/config") should be "vs-ssh.visualstudio.com".

Comment: This fixed the same issue I had with a self-hosted bitbucket server that had not been updated in a while. They list the [same solution on their forum](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/OpenSSH-8-7-and-ssh-rsa-host-key/qaq-p/1799373).

Comment: Works as described with Azure DevOps. Thank you!

Comment: fixed me up after upgrading in-place to ubuntu 22.04.  well done.

Answer (score 102):

OpenSSH will report the error
`no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa`
if the server it's connecting to is offering to authenticate over `ssh-rsa` ( `RSA/SHA1`).

Azure Devops (TFS) is offering to authenticate over `ssh-rsa`. As noted in [the answer by bk2204](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69875803), this algorithm is not considered cryptographically secure.

Since it's considered weak, OpenSSH [deprecated](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.2) using `SHA-1` in `8.2` in 2020-02-14.

> It is now possible[1] to perform chosen-prefix attacks against the
> SHA-1 hash algorithm for less than USD$50K. For this reason, we will
> be disabling the "ssh-rsa" public key signature algorithm that depends
> on SHA-1 by default in a near-future release.

Azure Devops *Services* subsequently [announced a patch](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/supporting-sha-2-algorithm-in-ssh-on-azure-devops/) to allow `SHA-2`

On may 5 2021, the Azure DevOps documentation was [updated](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/commit/101a19a9a22a7d02d7fc21081a17cd0210683d55#diff-ceb09094743c8512adc9a022d6f4e3dcdb7b0edca3b6d9d691181b10c31bc81b) to mention using `RSA 3072`.

#### Q: Is this true?

`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

#### Q: Which algorithms are supported?

Doesn't say anywhere. Probably only `ssh-rsa`.

#### Q: How do I use a cryptographically unsafe algorithm

Add this

```
  HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

To your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host your-azure-devops-domain
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

#### Q: Is Microsoft aware that this is a problem?

[Yes](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Support-elliptic-curve-ed25519-SSH-key/1396110)
[they](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-configure-SSH-key-exchange-met/848657)
[are](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-add-SSH-Public-Key-in-Azure-De/1608131).

#### Q: Do they care?

[No](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Missing-Support-of-SHA-2-algorithm-for-O/1562711#T-N1563419)
[it's a](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Missing-Support-of-SHA-2-algorithm-for-O/1562711#T-N1563459)
[feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Missing-Support-of-SHA-2-algorithm-for-O/1562711#T-N1567943)

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick for me after updating to Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: As of 2022-08-01, ssh-rsa is still what is used by Azure DevOps _Services_, so their claim of patching it in 2020 is false.

Answer (score 64):

According to [this post](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/unable-to-login-in-remotely-using-ssh-using-rsa-keys-after-last-update/85631/14), you can add `ssh.dev.azure.com` host config to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

> Final `~/.ssh/config` that worked for me:
>
> ```
> Host ssh.dev.azure.com
>     HostName ssh.dev.azure.com
>     User git
>     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
>     IdentitiesOnly yes
>     PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
>     HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
> ```

Comment: `IdentitiesOnly yes
 PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
 HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa`
Faced same issue after CodeCommit setup, pasting above 3 lines successfully authenticated git over SSH, Thanks!

Comment: but I'm still stuck. It was all working and suddenly stopped connecting codecommit..

Comment: This also works for HostNames like `vs-ssh.visualstudio.com`

Answer (score 54):

scp or ssh could used this

```
ssh -p 22 -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa  user@myhost
# or scp
scp -P 22 -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa  user@myhost
```

Comment: ssh-keygen -f "/home/qmm0/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "[10.0.0.28]:2222";ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa 10.0.0.28 -p 2222

Comment: SFTP: `sftp -P 22 -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa  user@myhost`

Comment: thank you for this! this also works on mac ventura 13.4

Comment: This answer is nice if you want to solve the problem once, or temporarily, while you're investigating or implementing a permanent server-side fix. In the past I've modified `.ssh/config` with workarounds, and then had to debug secondary issues later on.

Answer (score 20):

For those using Azure DevOps, you should use the following **~/.ssh/config**, as Azure has a thing with varying what url it returns in its **Clone Repository**:

```
Host ssh.dev.azure.com
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa

Host vs-ssh.visualstudio.com
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Answer (score 15):

In your `~/.ssh/config` file, add these lines.

```
Host *.drush.in
    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Answer (score 10):

I also got this problem, this worked for me:

```
cd ~/.ssh/
vim config

Host [Hostname]
User [User]
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

I got this problem for a few hostnames so now i have several of those configurations in my ssh config file.

Comment: and identity file?

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 steps:

1. Add config file (without extension) to your `~/.ssh/` directory.
2. Add below content to the config file:

   ```
   HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa    
   PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
   ```

Comment: This fixed it for me, just adding those 2 lines in `~/.ssh/config` fixed my use case after updating to Sonoma (on Mac).

Answer (score 4):

With NixOS 21.11 openSSH got updated to 8.8p1 ( see [Changelog](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/release-notes.html#sec-release-21.11) ). OpenSSH deprecated ssh-rsa along with a couple of other insecure ciphers.

If i understood correctly, you are only using nix as package manager and not NixOS. If that is the case you can follow the guides in the remaining answers (edit `~/.ssh/config`).

However, when you are using NixOS to configure your server you can re-enable `ssh-rsa` for the ssh client, by adding to your `configuration.nix`:

```
programs.ssh.extraConfig = ''
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
''
```

To re-enable the insecure ssh-rsa cipher for your openssh server (e.g. when legacy clients connect to the server), you can simply add the following lines to your `configuration.nix`:

```hs
services.openssh.extraConfig = ''
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
'';
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed. Unfortunately, the services.openssh stanza has two typos (transposed letters). I think it needs to be "PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms", just like in the programs.ssh stanza.

Comment: @antifuchs thanks, i've updated my response.

Answer (score 4):

Correction for the posted answer. I had the same issue and I fixed it with the following snippet from above with a tiny fix:

```
Host YOUR-DOMAIN
Hostname YOUR-DOMAIN
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
IdentitiesOnly yes
HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa
```

Dont forget to replace `YOUR-DOMAIN` with the domain you are using on AzureDevOps.

Answer (score 2):

The format of the workaround wasn't working for me for windows 10 and git version 2.32.0. This snippet worked for me

**Host** = Hostname.com
**IdentityFile** = ~/.ssh/id_rsa
**IdentitiesOnly** = yes
**HostkeyAlgorithms** = +ssh-rsa
**PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms** = +ssh-rsa

Answer (score 2):

I googled a lot a bout this mistake: I have Ubuntu 22.04 and here all my configuration.
I hope it will help someone.

### `linux@linux:~$ cat /home/username/.ssh/config`

```ini
Host *

KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512
Ciphers aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr

User username # it depends on your login; this one only for understanding

PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

And:

### `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```ini
# Ciphers and keying

Ciphers             aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512

HostkeyAlgorithms ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue on my windows machine while setting up the SSH key for bitbucket

Initially, the config file was not created when I generated the public and private key files using the **ssh-keygen** command, so I used **GitBash** to create the config file and wrote the below content on it.

To create the file

```
touch config
```

To open and update the created file

```
nano config
```

Content added to the config file

```
Host [Hostname]
   HostName [Hostname]
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   IdentitiesOnly yes
   PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
   HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

**Note:** If you are using your organization's bitbucket account, the hostname will be different or else by default it will be bitbucket.org

Answer (score 1):

By this way, it worked:

- Open terminal: cd ~/.ssh/
- Create config file: vim config

- Next steps you can use VIM to input the config file or use my way:

- Open Finder/ Go to Folder/ type: ~/.ssh
- Open the config file by TextEdit or SublimeText
- Paste the following code

> Host replaceMeByYourGitDomain
> HostName replaceMeByYourGitDomain
> User git
> IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsaenter code here
> IdentitiesOnly yes
> PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
> HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it turned out to be because my computer was referencing the wrong ssh.exe file.

Run the command:

```
which ssh.exe
```

If this does not return OpenSSH/ssh.exe then this is likely your issue.

Take the return value and rename the ssh.exe file as ssh.exe.org

Run

`which ssh.exe`

again and it should now show the OpenSSH/ssh.exe file.

Answer (score 0):

A concise solution to this: `ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa user@remote.server.com`

Answer (score -1):

For macOS, you actually need to edit `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` instead of `.ssh/config`. The local config wasn't applied for me.

Comment: Not true on my mac.  Not sure how yours is setup.  I am on the latest (Sonoma) and changing `~/.ssh/config` worked for me.